# Rollover on JLabel which consists of image within grid layout?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a code with grid layout and two JLabel images. I wan't some text to appear everytime I roll over each image. I am familiar on how to do this when the image is not a JLabel, but have searched all over the web to find how to do this while it is an unnamed JLabel. The two images I wan't to have, with separate roll over messages are:

```
ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("giraffe.png"));
            Icon windows = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("windows.png"));
```

Here is my code:

```
    public class giraffe implements ActionListener{


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Press ok, and see the amazing giraffe outside a window!");

            JDialog giraffewindow = new JDialog();
            Icon giraffe = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("giraffe.png"));
            Icon windows = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("windows.png"));

            giraffewindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));
            giraffewindow.add(new JLabel (windows));
            giraffewindow.add(new JLabel (giraffe));


            giraffewindow.pack();
            giraffewindow.setTitle("GIRAFFE!");
            giraffewindow.setVisible(true);
            giraffewindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

            /*
             * I want to have a rollover on EACH IMAGE so that when they rollover the image you see different text.
             */

        }
```

Thank you so much for the time you are taking for reading this, I really appreciate the effort you are putting into helping a fellow programmer!

Comment: I guess you'll need a `MouseListener` to track the `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` events and change the text of the label accordingly.  Start with [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Comment: `I am familiar on how to do this when the image is not a JLabel` - how would you do this?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Wouldn't he have to create his own class that extends JLabel, then implement MouseListener from there?

Comment: I would use something like .setRolloverIcon... Although that would be a rollover image, so I would use something like .setToolTipText. Although I am completely lost in this case.

Comment: @MadProgrammer It would be the way I would tackle his problem, is it not the best?

Comment: `I would use something like .setRolloverIcon...` - so you mean you know how to do it when you use a JButton? What does that have to do with text? `I would use something like .setToolTipText` yes, that is an option, but tooltip will only show after a period of time. You need to tell us the requirement.

Comment: Obviously the least period of wait time of hovering over the image would be the best case scenario, although for my own learning purposes I'd wan't to understand the multiple different ways I could do it. Do you have something in mind?

Comment: @WyattLowery It would depend, if you want to make a self contained, reusable component, yes you could extend a `JLabel`, equally, you could make a custom `MouseListener` which used the event source to determine if the source is a label and update the text so you could apply it to preexisting labels...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by having a look at [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

Basically, you want to attach a `MouseListener` to each label and monitor the `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` events, updating the label state as per your requirements

[image: LabelText]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                JLabel left = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(...))));
                left.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
                left.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
                left.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                left.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                left.setText(" ");
                JLabel right = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(...))));
                right.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
                right.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
                right.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                right.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                right.setText(" ");

                setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));

                add(left);
                add(right);

                left.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                        left.setText("I'm on the left");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                        left.setText(" ");
                    }
                });
                right.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                        right.setText("I'm on the right");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                        right.setText(" ");
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

You might also want to have a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! Out of curiosity though, is it possible to have the mouse listener have different outputs based on the number of times mouse listener is accessed? For example, if I hover over something once it displays "once" and if I hover over it twice it displays "twice"?

Comment: Yes, depending on how you setup the mouse listener, basically you just need a counter which you increment. If you're using a single listener, then you could use a Map if some kind

Answer (score 4):

You can also create a generic listener by doing something like:

```
ImageIcon giraffe = new ImageIcon(...);
giraffe.setDescription("Giraffe Description");
```

Then your listener might look something like:

```
MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
        JLabel label = (JLabel)e.getSource();
        ImageIcon icon = (ImageIcon)label;
        label.setText( icon.getDescription() );
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
        JLabel label = (JLabel)e.getSource();
        label.setText(" ");
    }
}
```

And you add the listener to the label:

```
JLabel giraffeLabel = new JLabel( giraffe );
giraffe.addMouseListener( ml );
```

The same listener can be used for your other JLabel because the event code knows with component generated the event.