# Can I split a glass pane up into two, and add a seperate mouselistener to each?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, format, glasspane

I have some code with two images under a glass pane. I want to make it so that each image is under its own glass pane, and each glass pane signals of its own mouselistener. Currently I have made both of them under one glass pane, with one mouselistener for the entire glass pane. Both images are in grid layout side by side, so it shouldn't be too hard to split the glass pane in half. Here is the code of just one glass pane, but note that I am trying to make two glass panes, and two **seperate** mouse listener classes for **each** image. This is just code with **one* mouse listener for **both** images:

```
package Buttons;


import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Giraffewindow extends JDialog {
public Giraffewindow() {
    JDialog giraffewindow = new JDialog();

    Icon giraffe = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("giraffe.png"));
    Icon windows = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("windows.png"));

    giraffewindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));
    giraffewindow.add(new JLabel(windows));
    giraffewindow.add(new JLabel(giraffe));


    giraffewindow.pack();
    giraffewindow.setTitle("GIRAFFE!");
    giraffewindow.setVisible(true);
    giraffewindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel glass = ((JPanel) giraffewindow.getGlassPane());
    glass.setVisible(true);
    status = new JLabel("I can change");

    glass.add(status);
    glass.setLayout(null);
    giraffemousehandler giraffemouse = new giraffemousehandler();
    glass.addMouseListener(giraffemouse);
    glass.addMouseMotionListener(giraffemouse); //Can I add mouse motion listener to a picture
    // setLayout(null);
}


JLabel status = null;

class giraffemousehandler extends MouseAdapter implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener { //MouseAdapter makes it so that you don't have to have all 7 implemented mouse listener methods

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        status.setBounds(e.getX(), e.getY(), 50, 60); //Makes JLabel follow mouse

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        status.setText("Enter);

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        status.setText("Exit");
        // status.setBounds(e.getX(), e.getY(), 5, 6);

    }

}
}
```

Here is the code on camickr's request, please note there are two separate mouse listeners, I would love to know how to do it otherwise. When the JLabel follows the mouse, 1) it is extremely far from the mouse, 2) it does not show the full JLabel and 3) It does not change after one exit/enter. I really appreciate the help, and here is the code based on camickrs advice:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class SSCCE extends JDialog {

public SSCCE() {
    JDialog giraffewindow = new JDialog();

    Icon giraffe = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("giraffe.png"));
    Icon windows = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("windows.png"));

    giraffewindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));
    JLabel giraffelabel = new JLabel();
    JLabel windowlabel = new JLabel();

    windowlabel.setIcon(windows);
    giraffelabel.setIcon(giraffe);

    giraffewindow.add(windowlabel);
    giraffewindow.add(giraffelabel);

    giraffewindow.setTitle("Title!");
    giraffewindow.setSize(1100, 600);
    giraffewindow.setVisible(true);
    giraffewindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel glass = ((JPanel) giraffewindow.getGlassPane()); //Glasspane
    glass.setVisible(true);

    status = new JLabel("I can change"); //This is the JLabel which should follow my mouse

    glass.add(status);
    glass.setLayout(null);

    giraffemousehandler giraffemouse = new giraffemousehandler();
    windowmousehandler windowmouse = new windowmousehandler();

    windowlabel.addMouseListener(windowmouse);
    giraffelabel.addMouseMotionListener(giraffemouse); //Can I add mouse motion listener to a picture

    // setLayout(null);
}

JLabel status = null;

class giraffemousehandler extends MouseAdapter implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener { //MouseAdapter makes it so that you don't have to have all 7 implemented mouse listener methods

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        status.setBounds(e.getX(), e.getY(), 50, 60); //Makes JLabel follow mouse

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        status.setText("Mouse is on giraffe");

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        status.setText("Mouse has left giraffe");
        // status.setBounds(e.getX(), e.getY(), 5, 6);

    }

}

class windowmousehandler extends MouseAdapter implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        status.setBounds(event.getX(), event.getY(), 50, 60); //Makes JLabel follow mouse

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {

        status.setText("Mouse is on window");

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {

        status.setText("Mouse has left window");
        // status.setBounds(e.getX(), e.getY(), 5, 6);

    }
}
}

public class Icallsscce {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        SSCCE object = new SSCCE();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider having a look at `JLayer` (for before Java 7, `JXLayer`)

Comment: What is it your trying to do achieve?  What actions do you want occur over the images which is different from glass pane?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I want to have different events over each image. The glass pane is just there so that the JLabel doesn't go under the pictures

Comment: Okay, I think you're going to have issues with the glasspane consuming mouse events before they get to the labels (and the grid layout might confuse your expectations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Almost every problem can be demonstrated in 10-50 lines of code if you truly understand what you are trying to achieve.

No. A component is a component, you can't split a component into two.

You have a couple of options:

1. If you add the MouseListener to the GlassPane you will then need to use the mouse point from the event and use the `Container.getComponentAt(...)` to determine which component the mouse is currently over. Note that the GlassPane covers the entire frame so the mouse point is relative to the frame which includes the Borders so you will first need to use the `SwingUtilities.convertPoint(...)` method to convert the mouse point to a point relative to the panel that you added the labels to.
2. If you add separate MouseListeners to each label then the mouse point will be relative to the label so you will need to add the "x" value of the label to the point on the glass pane when you move your popup label. I think this approach is easier. Note with this approach you can share the same listener, you just need to use the `getSource()` method of the MouseEvent to get the label.

Edit:

> how I can add the getSource() method to my mouseevent?

This was already answered 10 days ago: [Rollover on JLabel which consists of image within grid layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110101/rollover-on-jlabel-which-consists-of-image-within-grid-layout/32110583#32110583).

It get annoying when you don't even look at the code because it is not a complete program. We are not here to write the code for you. When someone takes the time to answer a question, the least you can do it take the time to understand the suggestion.

> 1) it is extremely far from the mouse,

I already answered that in this question. I stated `you will need to add the "x" value of the label..`. You need to do this because mouse events are generated relative to the component the listener is added to.

So for the giraffe label the value of x will start at 0 and increase as the mouse is moved to the right. However, the giraffe starts at the center of the Glass Pane, so you can't use 0 as the location of your popup label. You also need to include the x locaton of the giraffe.

So the basic code should be:

```
popupLabel.setLocation(e.getX() + giraffe.getLocation().x, e.getY());
```

Of course you should be using the "source" object (not the giraffe label) of the MouseEvent as demonstrated in the answer above. When you use the source object the code will work for both labels.

> 2) it does not show the full JLabel

because you are using "magic numbers" in your setBounds() method. Why did you use a number like "60" for the width of the label? Don't hard code numbers. Instead when you change the text of the label you can do:

```
label.setText(....);
label.setSize(label.getPreferredSize());
```

Now the label will have the proper width/height. Then when you move the label on the glass pane you just use the `setLocation(...)` method to position the label.

> It does not change after one exit/enter

You are implement a MouseListener and a MouseMotionListener, so you need to add both of those listeners to each component. So you need:

giraffe.addMouseListener(...);
giraffe.addMouseMotionListener(...);
window.addMouseListener(...);
window.addMouseMotionListener(...);

Again, remember you only need one class to implement the MouseListener and MouseMotionListener as demonstrated 10 days ago. The same instance of the listener can be added to both components which will help clean up your code.

Comment: Before I do this, my JLabel is supposed to follow my mouse. Will it still be on top of the glass pane, because before I added it to the glass pane, but now you are telling me to add it to the JLabel?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, do you mind explaining how I can add the getSource() method to my mouseevent?

Comment: I have tried your method, but now the when the JLabel follows the mouse, 1) it is extremely far from the mouse, 2) it does not show the full JLabel and 3) It does not change after one exit/enter

Comment: @Rich, 1) still waiting for you to "accept" an answer from your other question. Why do you think we should keep responding to your questions when you don't bother to "accept" answers? 2) I already told you that the location would need to be adjusted. You have not posted your updated code so I can't tell what you are doing. You make an effort if you want extra help.

Comment: `Every question I have has an accepted question,` - you "accepted" the answer 12 minutes ago. I commented in this posting over an hour ago. and I commented in the other posting (that you just accepted) over 2 hours ago. You received the answer in the other posting 7 hours ago, well before you even posted this question.

Comment: And don't forget when you post code to post a proper `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem. The code you currently posted is NOT a SSCCE. If I can't execute the code I'm not going to look at it. In any case I can't look at it until tomorrow, that is why you should always post a proper SSCCE with the question so people don't have to ask for more information.

Comment: I have posted a proper SSCCE code in my answer based on your suggestions. It should be able to be executed. Thank you so much for taking the time to look at it!

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your time and effort into these answers. I have indeed read your other answer, but I still did not understand how I can use the getSource() in the label itself. Do you mind helping me with that? I understand what getSource does, but do not understand how to use it, and how I will differentiate the two JLabels' mouse listeners without creating two different objects...? Please let me know. Again, I would really like to thank you, and I have liked this answer, and marked as best answer. Please let me know about the getSource(). Thanks!

Comment: `but I still did not understand how I can use the getSource() in the label itself.` - so did you ask a question in that posting? Start with the working example given to you in that question. Then instead of adding separate ActionListeners to add to the left/right labels, you create one ActionListener and add it to the labels as I demonstrated in my code example. If that doesn't help then search the forum for other examples that use getSource(). I don't understand your confusion. The source is the object that generated the event. So it will have a reference to one of the labels.

Answer (score 2):

I really think you're going to have issues with using a `MouseListener` on the `glassPane`, as this will consume mouse events, meaning that any of the other components won't actually be notified.

Instead, I'd use the glass and monitor the motion of mouse over it to find the components it's passing over and then change the "hover label" accordingly.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE;

public class Giraffewindow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                new Giraffewindow();
            }
        });
    }

    public Giraffewindow() {
        JDialog giraffewindow = new JDialog();

        try {
            Icon giraffe = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("...")));
            Icon windows = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("...")));

            JLabel left = new JLabel(windows);
            JLabel right = new JLabel(giraffe);

            giraffewindow.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            giraffewindow.add(left);
            giraffewindow.add(right);

            giraffewindow.pack();
            giraffewindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            giraffewindow.setTitle("GIRAFFE!");
            giraffewindow.setVisible(true);
            giraffewindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            JPanel glass = ((JPanel) giraffewindow.getGlassPane());
            glass.setVisible(true);
            status = new JLabel("I can change");
            status.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            status.setBackground(Color.RED);
            status.setOpaque(true);

            glass.add(status);
            glass.setLayout(null);
            giraffemousehandler giraffemouse = new giraffemousehandler();

            glass.addMouseMotionListener(giraffemouse);

            // setLayout(null);
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    JLabel status = null;

    class giraffemousehandler extends MouseAdapter implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener { //MouseAdapter makes it so that you don't have to have all 7 implemented mouse listener methods

        private Component last = null;

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Point p = e.getPoint();

            JRootPane rootPane = SwingUtilities.getRootPane(e.getComponent());
            Container contentPane = rootPane.getContentPane();
            Component comp = contentPane.getComponentAt(p);
            if (comp != last) {
                if (last != null) {
                    mouseExited(last);
                }
                if (comp != null) {

                    if (comp != contentPane) {
                        last = comp;
                        mouseEntered(comp);
                    } else {
                        last = null;
                    }

                }
            }

            status.setSize(status.getPreferredSize());
            status.setLocation(p.x, p.y);

        }

        protected void mouseExited(Component comp) {
            System.out.println("Exited");
            status.setText("Exited");
        }

        protected void mouseEntered(Component comp) {
            status.setText("Entered");
        }

    }
}
```

I wondering if tooltips would be easier...

Comment: Although you weren't marked best answer, I have thanked you by lliking your answer. Thanks so much!