# JLabel icon's color only changes when the .setText() is called

Tags: java, swing

I'm using [Ikonli Packs](https://kordamp.org/ikonli/) for my element icons and adding it to a `JLabel` works fine.

[image: icon]

I want to implement a hover feature but when I do, nothing happens *unless* I try to call the `.setText()` method of my `JLabel`.

I thought it might be obligatory to have text in order to detect the cursor, but the `JLabel` doesn't have text initially, yet it still detects it, but as I mentioned, if I don't have the `.setText()` as well, the icon color will not change.

There are many examples here and on other websites on how to implement hover for labels/buttons/etc., but they all have text in one shape or form.

There's also [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110101/rollover-on-jlabel-which-consists-of-image-within-grid-layout) which hovers over images, but yet again, changes the text, not the images themselves.

(The elements seen in the `MyForm.java` file have been added via the Swing Palette.)

#### MyForm.java

```java
package bruh;

import com.formdev.flatlaf.FlatDarkLaf;
import org.kordamp.ikonli.materialdesign2.MaterialDesignA;
import org.kordamp.ikonli.swing.FontIcon;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class MyForm extends JFrame {
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JLabel myLabel;

    public MyForm(String title) {
        super(title);

        this.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();

        Color mainColor = Color.RED;
        Color hoverColor = Color.WHITE;
        FontIcon icon = FontIcon.of(MaterialDesignA.ACCOUNT);
        icon.setIconSize(10);
        icon.setIconColor(mainColor);
        myLabel.setIcon(icon);

        myLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                icon.setIconColor(hoverColor);
                myLabel.setIcon(icon);
                //myLabel.setText("ENTERED");
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                icon.setIconColor(mainColor);
                myLabel.setIcon(icon);
                //myLabel.setText("EXITED");
            }
        });
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FlatDarkLaf.setup();

        JFrame frame = new MyForm("Hello World");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

#### Maven `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>bruh</groupId>
    <artifactId>bruh</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.formdev</groupId>
            <artifactId>flatlaf</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-core</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-swing</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-materialdesign2-pack</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: I'd recommend using an undecorated button instead. It can handle icon changes effortlessly. If you want to keep using the `org.kordamp.ikonli.swing.FontIcon` you might be best off taking it up with the developer.

Comment: "I'd recommend using an undecorated button instead. It can handle icon changes effortlessly." - Thank you. I used a button instead and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by **Andrew Thompson**, I used a `JButton` instead of `JLabel`.

```
package bruh;

import com.formdev.flatlaf.FlatDarkLaf;
import org.kordamp.ikonli.materialdesign2.MaterialDesignA;
import org.kordamp.ikonli.swing.FontIcon;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class MyForm extends JFrame {
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JButton myButton;

    public MyForm(String title) {
        super(title);

        this.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();

        Color mainColor = Color.RED;
        Color hoverColor = Color.WHITE;
        FontIcon icon = FontIcon.of(MaterialDesignA.ACCOUNT);
        icon.setIconSize(10);
        icon.setIconColor(mainColor);
        myButton.setIcon(icon);

        // Use these 2 lines to remove the decoration.
        myButton.setBorderPainted(false);
        myButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);

        myButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                icon.setIconColor(hoverColor);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                icon.setIconColor(mainColor);
            }
        });
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FlatDarkLaf.setup();

        JFrame frame = new MyForm("Hello World");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Now only the icon is visible as seen in the image from my original post.

Comment: Plus one not just for solving it based on a brief hint, but for posting the answer.